# How to put data from json response in an array in reactjs

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, fetch

im trying to show images from the database and loop through them with a map. Here is the code:

```
class Container extends React.Component
{
   
    state ={
        userData:[]
      }
    
    
     
    fethData= async()=>{
      fetch("http://localhost:5000/user") // could be any rest get url
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result =>
        this.setState({
          userData: result
         
        })
      );
    }
 
    
    
    componentDidMount() {
       this.fethData();
       
       alert(this.state.userData);
     
        $(function(){  
            //Make every clone image unique.  
              var counts = [0];
               var resizeOpts = { 
                 handles: "all" ,autoHide:true
               };    
              $(".dragImg").draggable({
                                    helper: "clone",
                                    //Create counter
                                    start: function() { counts[0]++; }
                                   });
           
           $("#dropHere").droppable({
                  drop: function(e, ui){
                          if(ui.draggable.hasClass("dragImg")) {
                $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());
              //Pointing to the dragImg class in dropHere and add new class.
                    $("#dropHere .dragImg").addClass("item-"+counts[0]);
                       $("#dropHere .img").addClass("imgSize-"+counts[0]);
                           
              //Remove the current class (ui-draggable and dragImg)
                    $("#dropHere .item-"+counts[0]).removeClass("dragImg ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging");
           
           $(".item-"+counts[0]).dblclick(function() {
           $(this).remove();
           });     
               make_draggable($(".item-"+counts[0])); 
                 $(".imgSize-"+counts[0]).resizable(resizeOpts);     
                  }
           
                  }
                 });
           
           
           var zIndex = 0;
           function make_draggable(elements)
           {    
               elements.draggable({
                   containment:'parent',
                   start:function(e,ui){ ui.helper.css('z-index',++zIndex); },
                   stop:function(e,ui){
                   }
               });
           }    
           
           
               
              });
    }
    
    

    changeColor(params) {
        this.setState({
            color: params.target.value
        })
    }

    changeSize(params) {
        this.setState({
            size: params.target.value
        })
    }
    
    render() {
      
        return (
            
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="tools-section">
                            <div className="color-picker-container">
                                Select Brush Color : &nbsp; 
                                <input type="color" value={this.state.color} onChange={this.changeColor.bind(this)}/>
                            </div>

                            <div className="brushsize-container">
                                Select Brush Size : &nbsp; 
                                <select value={this.state.size} onChange={this.changeSize.bind(this)}>
                                    <option> 5 </option>
                                    <option> 10 </option>
                                    <option> 15 </option>
                                    <option> 20 </option>
                                    <option> 25 </option>
                                    <option> 30 </option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                
                        <div className="board-container">
                            
                            
                        
                            <h4>Select picture!</h4>
                        
                                
                                   
                              
                         
                                    
                                           
                                            {this.state.userData.map((data) => (
                                            
                                            <div class="dragImg">
                                                
                                                  
                                                 <img src={data.picture} class="img"/> // column data received
                                               
                                                
                                              </div>
                                            ))}
                             
                                   
                                
                    
                        
                        
                            <div  id="dropHere">
                                
                            <Board color={this.state.color} size={this.state.size}></Board></div>
                            
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>
           
        );
    }

    
}



export default Container
```

I would like to put data from function fethData into userData array. But when i run the website i get an alert that userData is undefined. Why is nothing added to userData?

This is the json data fetched from the database:

```
[{"idpictures":1,"picture":"images/kitten.jpg","title_picture":"Cat"},{"idpictures":2,"picture":"images/puppy.jpg","title_picture":"Dog"}]
```

I would like the data to be stored like this:

```
userData:[{idpictures:1,picture:"images/kitten.jpg",title_picture:"Cat"}]
```

Guys I solved it. This is what I changed about my code:

```
constructor(){
     super();
      this.state ={
          userData:[]
        }
    }
    
  
    
    
    async componentDidMount() {
      const url = "http://localhost:5000/user";
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json(); 
      this.setState({userData: data});
      console.log(this.state.userData);
       
       if (this.state.userData) {alert(this.state.userData)}
```

Comment: `Why is nothing added to userData?` Most likely because the fetching is not finished before the component has mounted.

Comment: It still tells me undefined when i put JSON.parse

Comment: @MikaelsSlava How can i make it finish before it mounts?

Comment: Well, thats tricky. I would fetch in a parent component and mount this component with a prop containing said data. Or, if you don't need the data to be there once the component has mounted, just use componentDidUpdate instead and wrap the alert in an if statement `if (this.state.userData) {alert(this.state.userData)}`

Comment: @MikaelsSlava Hmm still not working now it gives me empty alert

Comment: @dvidvid can you post the full component? Where is the constructor? Why are you defining the state with just `state = {}` not `this.state = {}`?

Comment: @MikaelsSlava I added full component. There is no constructor. Honestly got no idea why i did that I think I got that from a tutorial somewhere. But if you know what I could improve in the code i would appreciate that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the state of the component in the constructor. Also all data fetching in JS is asynchronous. Notice the `.then` in the fetch function you wrote. It contains code that will be executed once the response comes back.

```
class Container extends React.Component
{
   constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state ={
       userData:[]
    }
   }
    
    fethData = async() => {
      fetch("http://localhost:5000/user") // could be any rest get url
      .then(response => response.json()) // you might not need this, depends on the response
      .then(result =>
        this.setState({
          userData: result
         
        })
      );
    }
 
    componentDidUpdate() {
       alert(this.state) // This should show your data (when it gets here)
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
       this.fethData();
       
       alert(this.state.userData); // this will fire before the response from localhost:5000/user gets here
    }
        
}
export default Container
```

Answer (score 0):

ReactJS is different from Vue, use: `this.state.userData` to access userData. And `fetchData` is a asynchronous function, you can't get it's result synchronously.

Comment: for some reason when i do that ```this.state.userData: JSON.parse(result)``` it gives me three errors in this line which says ':' and ',' expected

Comment: What is this `this.state.userData: JSON.parse(result)`?

The `this.setState` function you wrote is ok. The way you get the state is not

Comment: ```this.state.userData: JSON.parse(result)``` is what i write in setstate to put the json into userData array

Comment: Leave it as it was (in the question). In the alert change it from `this.userData` to `this.state.userData`

Comment: @MikaelsSlava Hmm still gives me an empty alert. I did console log and says its Array(0) with nothing in it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example

```
  fethData= ()=>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{

     fetch("http://localhost:5000/user") // could be any rest get url
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(result =>
       this.setState({userData: result},()=>{
           resolve();
       })
     );
    })
   }

  async componentDidMount(){
    await this.fetchData();
    alert(this.state.userData);
  }
```